# Weird behaviour smb.conf create mask

Tags: permissions, 22.04, samba, zfs, samba4

I have set up a samba share to connect with windows 11.
I tried to change the default permissions to -RW-RW---- with `create mask = 0660`
But i get -RW-R-----.
When i try `create mask = 0460` i get -R--RW---- which is expected.
It looks like i cant give group write permissions when the user has write permissions.
Umask = 0022 but when i change it, it doesn't affect anything.

/data1 is a zfs pool. Could this change the behaviour?

version: Version 4.15.13-Ubuntu

`/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

[data1]
   comment = Shared Directory
   path = /data1
   valid users = @admin
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   writable = yes
   create mask = 0660
```